# SQL Execution failed: Error Binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I've tried some solutions from different questions, but still getting this error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT REAL_ESTATE.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER, MAX(PRICE.UPDATE_DATE) AS MAX_DATE, PRICE.RE_PRICE FROM REAL_ESTATE INNER JOIN PRICE WHERE UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER = (?)': Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

My code looks like this:

```
    IDs = []
    i = 0
    items = Saved.query.filter_by(userID=current_user.id).order_by(Saved.id)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('REDB.db')
    for item in items:
        realityID = conn.execute('SELECT UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER FROM REAL_ESTATE WHERE UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER = ?', (item.unqNum,)).fetchone()
        IDs.append(realityID[0])
        i = i + 1
    print(IDs)
    more_info = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT REAL_ESTATE.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER, MAX(PRICE.UPDATE_DATE) AS MAX_DATE, PRICE.RE_PRICE FROM REAL_ESTATE INNER JOIN PRICE WHERE UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER = (?)', conn, params=(IDs,))
    conn.close()
    print(more_info)
    return render_template("saved.html", items=items, more_info=more_info)
```

From items I am getting unique number of real estate. These numbers then want to use to find in my database, where I update prices of real estate daily.

Hopefully you can understand my problem, can anybody help?

Comment: Try printing both the type and value of item.unqNum to see what you've got. Assuming there is a value, then consider whether it's applicable to the UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER column in your database

Comment: does running the query directly with `conn` instead of `pd.read_sql_query` give the correct results?

Comment: The type of unqNum is str and column UPDATE_RE_NUMBER is TEXT. Is it ok?

Comment: The problem is not in the first query but in the second. You use `IDs` for the parameter and `IDs` is a list.

Comment: It is supposed to be a list, so I can take out all the real estate I need, is there a way of doing so?

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked duplicate shows how you can construct a delete statement using a list of ids.